# Github actions Connection error w/ Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, github-actions

I have a node js api that connects with sequelize to a mySQL database. I wrote a script to reset the database every time tests are ran. I am building a CI/CD pipeline and whenever the script is ran i get the following message:

```
throw new SequelizeErrors.ConnectionError(err);
                ^

ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
...
parent: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
...
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12) {
    fatal: true,
    code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
  },
  original: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

This is the part of the pipeline that fails:

```
tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RootPassword }}
      MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE: test
    ...
      - uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
        with:
          mysql root password: ${{ secrets.RootPassword }}
          mysql database: test
      - name: api testing
        run: cd api && npm run test
      ...
```

This is the `npm run test`

```
"test": "npm run resetDevDb && cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose"
"resetDevDb" : "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node db/scripts/reset-development-db.js"
```

The reset database Script:

```
const resetDb = async () => {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  await Book.sync({ force: true });
  await Author.sync({ force: true });
  await User.sync({ force: true });

  await Promise.all(
    users.map(async (user) => {
      await User.create(user);
    })
  );

  await Promise.all(
    books.map(async (book) => {
      await Book.create(book);
    })
  );

  await Promise.all(
    authors.map(async (author) => {
      await Author.create(author);
    })
  );
  console.log("Database reseted");
};
```

The sequelize config:

```
const developmentConfig = {
  dialect: "mysql",
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.MYSQL_DEVELOPMENT_HOST,
  logging: console.log,
};
```

And initialization

```
const { database, username, password, ...options } = require("./config.js");
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, options);
module.exports = sequelize;
```

I have ran this exact pipeline with (I believe) the exact same config and was working fine. After changing the remote repository a few times (And adding the secret.RootPassword) to the new repository I started getting this connection error. From some by hand debugging I figure the error ocurrs during the  `Book.sync({ force: true })` but I'm not sure if it has something to do with the miromutth/mysql action. Thanks!

Note: When I run `npm run test` locally everything works great, all the tables drop and are created again and filled, and the tests run and pass normally.